# httpconnection stringitem in j2me

Tags: java-me

I have wriiten an httpconnection app that returns headlines and links form a website and display on the form/stringtiem.
How can I seperate the headlines from the links given that all of the them are now concatenated into one string which displays on one stringitem?

Here's the code:

```
String line = results.toString();
            int position = line.indexOf("<h2 class=\"cross-head\">");
            position = line.indexOf(">", position);
            //
            int position2 = line.indexOf("</h3>", position);
            //
            res = line.substring(position + 1, position2);
            //
            while (res.indexOf("<") != -1) {

                int beginTag;
                int endTag;

                beginTag = res.indexOf("<");
                endTag = res.indexOf(">");
                if (beginTag == 0) {
                    res = res.substring(endTag + 1, res.length());
                } else {
                    res = res.substring(0, beginTag)
                            + res.substring(endTag + 1, res.length());
                }
                description = replace(res, "&quot;", "\"");
                description = replace(description, "&nbsp;", "");
                description = replace(description, "&rsquo;", "'");
                description = replace(description, "&lsquo;", "'");
                description = replace(description, "&ldquo;", "\"");
                description = replace(description, "&rdquo;", "\"");
                description = replace(description, "&ndash;", "-");

                description = replace(description, "&amp;", "&");
                description = replace(description, "&#039;", "'");
                description = replace(description, "Â", "");

            }
            //

            // End Parsing

            // display the page contents on the phone screen
            StringItem resultField = new StringItem(null, description,
                    Item.HYPERLINK);
            form.append(resultField);
```